# Contact layout sections displaying in newly created page layout

Tags: page-layout, record-type, pagelayoutassignment

We have created a record type(Customer Groups) and a page layout(Customer Groups). 
And assigned the new page layout to the "Customer Group" record type in Pagelayout Assignment.

However, when we tried to create a new customer under "Customer Group" recordtype,

1. Contact Record Type is displayed as Customer individual instead of Customer Group
2. And the layout is different which is having the Customer Group layout plus some sections from Contact layout too.

Please help with this challenge.

Thanks.

Comment: is the record type enabled for your profile ?

Comment: Ya. It is enabled for my profile.

Comment: So to verify everythign above:  Both record types are available, the record types are available to the profile of the user creating the Contact record, and the page layouts are assigned to each record type and for each profile?

Comment: Ya everything assigned. But when we are trying to create a contact under Customer Group record type, layout is different and Standard field Contact record type also displayed as Customer individual instead of new one.